# Simple way to access code from a private Github repository in google colab?

Tags: github, import, google-colaboratory, private-repository

I would really like to be able to import modules from a private Github repository into google colab.

I know I have access to this private repo because I pull and push from it regularly.

I went into Settings on google colab and connected my GitHub account, so that when I go to this section it says "You GitHub account is connected to your Google Drive account."

However, when I run the following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(`/content/drive`)
```

I don't see any GitHub subfolder in `/content/drive/MyDrive/`

Alternatively, [this site](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/359) recommended going into GitHub "Developer settings" and using a personal access token. I gave this personal access token every possible permission, but again when I try to git clone the private repo, I get the following error message: `remote: Repository not found.`

I think the problem may be that when I go to my GitHub account and look at the tab "Repositories," I don't see this Repository. I am able to push and pull from it though.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on / help me get access in colab to this repo? I am very confused; in general there seems to be many ways to do this online, but none of them are quite working for me, and I don't understand why it's so easy to mount the Google Drive but so hard to sync with GitHub.